# Can I use other softwares than Linger to run a self-paced reading task

Tags: social-psychology, experimental-psychology

I want to run an SPR experiment where participants will read sentences at their own pace. My problem lies in the fact of using  2 different languages English and Arabic at the same time. I tried it with Linger, but I failed to upload the files. 
Could any one of you suggest another software by which I can run SPR tasks in Arabic and English?

Comment: How much programming are you willing to do?

Comment: What does SPR stand for?

Comment: self-paced reading, I belive

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ibex, if you want to run it online: http://spellout.net/ibexfarm/

But in any case you should be able to upload the files in Linger, you'll need to do it centered since Linger doesn't support right-to-left languages. And you should check the encoding of the files. It should be ISO 8859-15 and *not* UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you Bruno. I could upload the English files on Linger and it worked. For the Arabic ones, i could not cause there is a prob of encoding which i could nt solve :/

Comment: did you check that the files are encoded as ISO 8859-15? If you use windows, I think notepad lets you change it with Save as...

Comment: Houw shoud i do that? I pasted the Arabic items as they are. Linger could open them, but  words changed. Linger Documentation says " For Non English languages, you need to encode the items, introduction, break, and conclusion files using a language-specific extended-ASCII encoding, if they are to include any non-English text. This can be done with Word and possibly with Wordpad or Notepad under Windows, or SimpleText on a Mac.
When you save the file, choose plain text (not rich text format) and then select the appropriate Unicode encoding for your language. I tried it, but  in vain.

Comment: I don't know. If they are saved as ISO 8859-15, they should work fine. I never used Linger for Arabic, only for Spanish and German, but the accents and special characters were fine when I used ISO 8859-15. The second option is to use http://spellout.net/ibexfarm/, it has an active forum, and I remember someone using it for Arabic. (I used it for Hebrew which should be the same).

Answer (score 1):

There's a program called Paradigm that has built-in support for Self-Paced Reading,
it also handles Arabic characters. You'll just type in your sentences and then use back-slashes to specify each segment. For example:

The actress\shot\the officer\who\was standing\on the balcony

Paradigm will log a timestamp for the onset of each segment (in Excel) so
it's pretty easy to analyze.

Here's their website:

http://www.paradigmexperiments.com

Comment: Thank you noodle ! I could upload  the files in Linger.  My probl lies in the encoding procedure now for the Arabic stimuli. I had a look at Paradigm. It s interesting too.